# react-native run-android asks for Realm?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm on a mac mini (not windows).  I did the following commands:

1. cd Documents/
2. react-native init helloworld
3. cd helloworld
4. react-native run-android

What happens next is the android simulator will load up.  Then I get the red screen, with the error message:

> Missing Realm constructor.  Did you run "react-native link realm"?  Please see https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#missing-realm-constructor for troubleshooting

But why is it complaining about realm?  I just initialized the project, I didn't even include any packages yet.  I have used realm on other projects...is my mac caching some settings somewhere?  I don't see any mention of realm in my package.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, after i restarted my mac mini, this problem went away.